# How can I set default parameters for mutable structs in Julia?

Tags: struct, constructor, julia, default

Is there a way to add default parameters for mutable structs in Julia?

I'm trying to write something like the following:

```
mutable struct Scale
    # Set default values that will be changed by fit!()
    domain_min::Float64 = 0.0
    domain_max::Float64 = 1.0
    range_min::Float64  = 0.0 
    range_max::Float64  = 1.0
end

function fit!(data::Array)
    # Set struct params here using `data`
end
```

Is there a way to do this or should I try a different approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I prefer using `Parameters.jl` because it provides also a nicer way the `struct`s are displayed which is much nicer for debugging:

```
julia> using Parameters

julia> @with_kw struct A          
       a::Int=5                   
       b::String="hello"          
       c::Float64                 
       end;                                 
                                  
julia> A(c=3.5)                   
A                                 
  a: Int64 5                      
  b: String "hello"               
  c: Float64 3.5
```

Answer (score 9):

This is exactly what `Base.@kwdef` does:

```
julia> Base.@kwdef mutable struct Scale
           # Set default values that will be changed by fit!()
           domain_min::Float64 = 0.0
           domain_max::Float64 = 1.0
           range_min::Float64  = 0.0 
           range_max::Float64  = 1.0
       end
Scale

# All parameters to their default values
julia> Scale()
Scale(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)

# Specify some parameter(s) using keyword argument(s)
julia> Scale(range_min = 0.5)
Scale(0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0)
```

Comment: Technically `Base.@kwdef` is an internal macro and thus subject to change (even though it is used quite a lot in the wild). Might be worth mentioning [Parameters.jl](https://github.com/mauro3/Parameters.jl) which has a public and stable interface for essentially the same thing.

Comment: FWIW, there is also [FieldDefaults.jl](https://github.com/rafaqz/FieldDefaults.jl).

Answer (score 5):

Or you can also just go the long way and define it yourself with constructors, as you would normally do if you want to instantiate it in several possible ways.

```
mutable struct Scale                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    # Set default values that will be changed by fit!()
    domain_min::Float64      
    domain_max::Float64      
    range_min::Float64        
    range_max::Float64       
end

# With default values, but no keywords
julia> Scale(dmin=1.,dmax=2.,rmin=1.,rmax=2.) = Scale(dmin, dmax, rmin, rmax)
Scale

julia> Scale(3.,4.)
Scale(3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0)

# With keyword arguments:
julia> Scale(;dmin=1.,dmax=2.,rmin=1.,rmax=2.) = Scale(dmin, dmax, rmin, rmax)
Scale

julia> Scale(rmax=3., rmin=1.2)
Scale(1.0, 2.0, 1.2, 3.0)
```

Notice the difference between the two constructors, one has a semicolon `;` the other not. I would not recommend using both constructors at the same time, this may lead to some confusion.